# como pasar datos de un fragment a un activity?

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

holaa amigos una consulta como puedo pasar datos de un fragment que esta contenido en un activity a este mismo activity? no se si me dejo entender, pero quiero pasar datos de mi fragment que esta incluido en mi activity a este mismo activity que lo incluye:

aqui esta parte de mi codigo en mi activity para insertar el fragment al

```
  FrameLayout(container) que tiene esta activity :

 if(view.getId() == R.id.btnUbicacionMakeReserva){

        if(verificacion>=1){
                verificacion = 1;

            Fragment fragmentoSelectUbicacion = new SelectUbicacion();

 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
 replace(R.id.containerMakerReserva,fragmentoSelectUbicacion).commit();


        }

    }
```

y bueno tengo SelectUbicacion fragment vacio pero mi idea es poder acceder a un Objeto propio de clase Ubicacion que tengo como propiedad en mi activity pero desde mi fragment al presionar un boton sea como sea quiero acceder desde este fragment a esa propiedad Ubicacion y pasarles datos desde este fragment alguna ayuda porfavor?
o algun ejemplo? en java muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola. Dado que tu fragmento pertenece a la activity, desde el fragmento puedes acceder a los datos de la activity haciendo esto: `((Nombre_de_tu_activity)this.getActivity()).metodo_u_objeto_de_tu_activity`. Yo lo uso para acceder desde el fragmento a objetos definidos en la activity, pero entiendo que debería funcionarte para ejecutar un método de la activity también. Prueba a ver.

Comment: Muchas gracias mi amigo, si me funciono como te doy puntos en stackOverFlow?